# The graph api do not return good data, why?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am using the graph api to catch the likes, shares and comments of the photos that are in an album. In most it does well, but there are a few that gets the likes, shares and comments the album and not the picture. I dont know why.

I use php, and two fql:

```
//get all photo ids of one album

$user_id= "my user id";
$photo_limit= "my limit";
$album_name="my album name";
$access_token= "my access token";

$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com'.
'fql?q=SELECT+object_id+FROM+photo+WHERE+album_object_id+in+
(SELECT+object_id,+name+FROM+album+WHERE+owner+=+'.$user_id.'
+and+name+=+"'.$album_name.'")+limit+'.$photo_limit. '&access_token=' . $access_token;

$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);



//print the likes, shares, and comments of all photos
foreach ($fql_query_obj["data"] as $photo_id){

$id = $photo_id["object_id"];
$fql_query_url_1 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.
'fql?q=SELECT+like_info.like_count,+comment_info.comment_count,+share_count,+
created_time+from+stream+where+post_id+in
(Select+page_story_id+from+photo+where+object_id+=+'.$id.')'.
'&access_token='.$access_token;

$fql_query_result_1 = file_get_contents($fql_query_url_1);
$fql_query_obj_1 = json_decode($fql_query_result_1, true);

echo $fql_query_obj_1["data"][0]["like_info"]["like_count"].",".
$fql_query_obj_1["data"][0]["comment_info"]["comment_count"].",".
$fql_query_obj_1["data"][0]["share_count"]."\n";

}
```

In some photos in the loop returns bad data. why???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I use cookbook. Sometimes dinner doesn't taste good. Why?" Exactly how are we supposed to provide **ANY** kind of help without ANY code or ACTUAL useful details?

Comment: I suggest you do not use `SELECT object_id FROM photo` but `SELECT pid FROM photo` instead. The pid is the actual photo id.

Comment: I have changed object_id for pid and  occurred the same.